# Autodesk Forge Viewer: Change Texture in IFC Model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, ifc

we run a webapplication using Autodesk Forge. In the webapplication we'd like to change surface apperances. Therefore we use the following Audodesk functions

```js
...
event.fragIdsArray.forEach(frag => {
const model = this.viewer.model;
model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(frag, this.material)
var object = this.viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(this.viewer.impl.model, frag)
object.updateAnimTransform()
}
```

The code works fine for Autodesk Revit imported model. Using imported IFC models does not work as expected. Both models were imported to the AD Forge viewer by ADs model derivate api.

To geht our expected results we tried to use MeshBasicMaterial and MeshPhongMaterial. Both with the same result: Revit model is fine, IFC model aint so.

In Order to lookup for some workaround we tried to copy the fragment meshes and creating overlays with the same mashes and changed materials. Code was like

```js
...
var obj = this.viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(this.viewer.impl.model, frag)
var meshProxy = new THREE.Mesh(obj.geometry, this.material);
meshProxy.matrix.copy(obj.matrixWorld);
meshProxy.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
meshProxy.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
meshProxy.frustumCulled = false;
this.viewer.impl.addOverlay("parkett", meshProxy);
...
```

The result is shown in the image (right side is the expected result):

[image: left side: Texture added to IFC. Right side: Same with rvt model]

Somehow it looks like the image texture is not shown "detailed" enough...

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

From the question I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Are there no visible changes when applying a custom material to IFC models? Or is the custom material applied, but in a "wrong way"?

If the custom material is not applied at all, make sure that the model is **not** consolidated. You can ensure that using `viewer.model.unconsolidate();`.

If the custom material is applied but its texture doesn't look correct, it could be because the geoemtries in the IFC model do not include proper texture coordinates. In that case you would have to map the texture yourself, for example, using a custom shader: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/custom-texture-mapping/public/CustomTextureExtension.js.

Comment: As you can See on the left, the material is applied but does not look correct. The correct look is on the right side of the picture. We‘ll try your suggestions and keep you informed! Thank you in advance